# Rally Race with no headset?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Standard races can be switched to Rally mode, which co-driver has to lead the blinded driver to next checkpoint.

But what if the co-driver has no headset for voice chat ? Any alternative buttons / ways to guide the driver.

*Surprisingly the game didn't check the existence of headset.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Left and right on the D-pad will flash an arrow on the screen, however my driver didn't appear to find this very useful on the one occasion I have tried it (I didn't realise when I started the race that my headset was dead).

There doesn't appear to be any granularity in the arrows - you either have an arrow on or off, so trying to guide someone to turn slightly can be difficult.

Answer (score 3):

You still have the usage of the Left/Right buttons to tell the driver when to turn and in which direction.

However it's still a lot less accurate than a real voice-chat ;)

Note also that if you want to do Rally Race only for the trophy/achievement, a lot of players are doing it in really short race so they already know the path without the copilot having to say anything.